# What is the point of private member in typescript?

Tags: typescript

All:

Just wondering why typescript provides private modifier but still be able to access that member in the transpiled JS file, then what is the point of private?

Comment: Perhaps you could go in to what about "Because accessing them illegally is a compile-time error" isn't sufficient?

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh Thanks, so basically the developer still need to take care the design  of class

Comment: FYI, you can also access private members of types in most other OO languages as well, if you get a reference to them. A "private member" is a design-time concept, not runtime.

Comment: You can use reflection in C# for example and access private variables of a class object as well as execute it's private methods. Like John White mentioned, private is only a design time concept.

Comment: This was already asked/requested a few times :) Links:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1537         https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/448054          https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3151

And so on and so on..